# Centering image both horizontally/vertically cross browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am faced with a CSS issue that i need help with.
I have many images of different sizes in a directory and I am dynamically listing them showing the following view: (I am only showing two images just as an example) [image]

Heres my HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="image_container">
        <div class="image_overlay">
            <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/n2ig5j.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div>SOME TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <div class="image_container">
        <div class="image_overlay">
            <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/wri2s9.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div>SOME TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.image {
    width: 245px;
    height: 235px;
    margin: 15px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ccc;
}

.image .image_container {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image .image_container .image_overlay {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    height:180px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.image .image_container .image_overlay img {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.footer{
    text-align:center;
}
```

It works great on Chrome but when I run it on Firefox it messes up. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code or how I need to rewrite it in order to fix it?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/urhxxqpm/)

Comment: I don't understand what the expected result is for that jsFiddle.

Comment: did you try viewing it both on Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: What about this is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/urhxxqpm/1/

Comment: When the images are of different size it does not work on Firefox

Comment: @CodeGodie I see it now, I posted a fix in my answer below :)

Comment: Ok thanks, give me a few I will check your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `table-layout: fixed` like this

```
.image .image_container {
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/urhxxqpm/3/

also more to read: http://www.carsonshold.com/2014/07/css-display-table-cell-child-width-bug-in-firefox-and-ie/